# listbox with 3 values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to assign value like this in a listbox?

```
$("#transfernumber").append("" + couponnumber + "");
```

I am having 3 values such as `id`, `amount` and `couponnumber`. I have to display the coupon number and I want to retrieve amount when selecting list box.

Comment: Can you create a js fiddle or something like this?

Comment: @abhitalks: The original edit was worse, adding code blocks around plain text.

Comment: @abhitalks: it appears the first person who edited the post added that. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the element as option to listbox. like this:

```
 $('#transfernumber').append('<option value="amount">coupon_num</option>');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Qrsg/)**

Comment: how to get coupon amount if i select it

Comment: You can use: `$('#transfernumber').val()` to get the value. as you need it on select, you need to write this code in change event for select `#transfernumber`

Comment: $("#transfernumber").append("<option value='" + couponid + "' data-amount='"+amount+"'>" + couponnumber + "</option>"); i used this code and how to get amount if i select it ?

Comment: @NandhiniDevi: have you used `$('#transfernumber').val()` ??

Comment: i am getting only id value and not amount value .i need amount value

Comment: How are you appending the option. can you share the html.

Comment: i used this code for appending and i need amount when i select it $("#transfernumber").append("<option value='" + couponid + "' data-amount='"+amount+"'>" + couponnumber + "</option>");

Comment: Try this `$('#transfernumber').data('amount')`

Comment: getting only empty value

Comment: can you share the fiddle??

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this one by using html5 `custom attributes`. `data-amount`

```
$("#transfernumber").append("<option value='" + couponid + "' data-amount='"+amount+"'>" + couponnumber + "</option>");
```

To retrieve this one by using `.data()`

```
var amount = $("#transfernumber").data( "amount");
```

[Jquery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

[Code Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6u2n/5/)

Comment: how to get the coupon amount if i select it ?

Comment: can you create fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

you can use .attr for this

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
$( "option" ).attr('id','test');
$( "option" ).attr('amount',5757);
$( "option" ).attr('coupon','testcoupon');
}); 
</script>
<select>
<option>hiiii</option> 
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C6u2n/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can add as follows

```
$('#transfernumber').append(
    $('<option/>', {
        value: '1',
        'data-amount': '100',
        html: 'couponnumber'
    })
);
```